# With AS3's XML find/filter operators, how to find children of an XML node when a tag is repeated?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

This is probably best illustrated by an example:

```
var xml1:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value1</key> </root>");
var xml2:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value1</key> <key>value2</key> </root>");
var xml3:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value1</key> <key2>value2</key2> </root>");
for each (var xml:XML in [ xml1, xml2, xml3 ])
{
    var result:XMLList = xml.(key == "value1").key;
}
```

In all three cases, I expect the filtered XMLList to have one node (result.length() == 1).  This is the case when operating on xml1 and xml3. However, nothing is found when filtering xml2 (result.length() == 0).  The crucial difference seems to be that in xml2, the "key" child tag is repeated.

Is this a bug (compiler? runtime?) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured out how this works.  I had misunderstood the syntax.

In my original example, xml.(key == "value1") selects a root node where the "key" property matches the string "value1".

In the case of xml1 and xml3, where there's only one "key" node, the value of xml.key is a single-element XMLList which string-casts to its text value, so the comparison with "value1" works.

In the case of xml2, where there are two "key" nodes, the value of xml.(key == "value1") is a two-element XMLList which string-casts two the full XML-encoded contents of the XML nodes, tags and all.  So the comparison with "value1" fails and the value of the expression is empty.

No compiler or runtime bug, just a confused programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would have *expected* it to return an `XMLList` of **length 2** in the case of `xml2`. It *should* select parent elements which contains a node named "key" with the value "value1", then filter **all** the nodes named "key".

Not sure why it doesn't, though. This is some E4X syntax that would do what I describe above:

```
var result:XMLList = xml.(descendants("key").text().contains("value1")).key;
```

`result` lengths:

- xml1: 1
- xml2: 2
- xml3: 1

---

On the other hand, if what you're expecting is ***only*** the nodes named "key" and with the value "value1", you can try this:

```
var result:XMLList = xml..key.(text() == "value1");
```

`result` lengths:

- xml1: 1
- xml2: 1
- xml3: 1

Comment: In your second snippet, isn't name() == "key" redundant, since xml..key already selects only "key" nodes?

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. I wrote the answer too late in the night. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Figured it out!  I wrote my own answer, but thanks very much for helping me understand this syntax.  Had never seem E4X before.

Answer (score 0):

AS3's XML objects have some pretty cool tricks,
Listing based on the tag name is super simple.

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value1</key> <key>value2</key> </root>");
var result:XMLList = xml.key;
```

That will create an XMLList of length 2 with every node with the tag 'key' you can also expand this for certain child nodes (i.e. xml.doors.locks.key).

You can also make lists based on a nodes attributes by using the prefix '@'.

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<root> <key name=\"k1\">value1</key> <key name=\"k2\">value2</key> <key name=\"k3\">value3</key> </root>");
var result:XMLList = xml.key.@name;
```

You can also concatenate if you have more than one list.

```
var xml1:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value1</key> <key>value2</key> <key>value3</key> </root>");
var xml2:XML = new XML("<root> <key>value4</key> <key>value5</key> <key>value6</key> </root>");
var list:XMLList = xml1.key;
list += xml2.key;
```

Hope this helps.